# function lines after httpRequest are not executed in groovy jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

None of the lines after making `httpRequest` are getting executed. Everything else works fine in this function. What could be going wrong here?

However, network request is going fine and I am able to see the response in the console. `httpRequest` is being made via [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin)

I've even tried `CURL` - but lines after curl are not executed.

```
@NonCPS
def doPRCommentBasedTesting() {
    def causes = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()
    def commentURL
    for(cause in causes) {
        if (cause.class.toString().contains("GitHubPullRequestCommentCause")) {
            commentURL = cause.getCommentUrl()
            commentURL = commentURL.substring(commentURL.lastIndexOf("-") + 1)
            println "This job was caused by job " + commentURL

            def url1 = "https://<git_url>/api/v3/repos/<owner>/<repo>/issues/comments/" + commentURL

            def commentText = httpRequest authentication: '<auth_cred>', url: url1, consoleLogResponseBody: true

            println commentText
            println commentText.getClass()
            println "hello world, how are you doing today?"

        }
        else {
            println "Root cause : " + cause.toString()
        }
    }

    println "==============================="
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non cps function does not have the ability to pause in between because it runs in a go. You need to put network call into a different function that is not marked as nonCPS and then it will work. In general the nonCPS block should be very small and limited to code that cannot be serialised